# Method with generic type parameter inside Swift extension

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming

While trying to implement a simple lazy list in Swift, I tried creating an extension for enum in Swift, with a generic method inside (emulating a type class-like behavior, as I'm trying out Swift while being a Scala developer most of the time), like so:

```
enum LazyList<A>{
    case Elem(x: A, xs: () -> LazyList<A>)
    case Nil()
}

extension LazyList {
    func map<B>(f: (A) -> B) -> LazyList<B> {
        func lazyMap(l: LazyList<A>, lf: (A) -> B) -> LazyList<B> {
            switch l {
            case let .Elem(e, es):
                return LazyList.Elem(x: lf(e), xs: {() -> LazyList<B> in return lazyMap(es(), lf: lf)})
            case .Nil:
                return LazyList.Nil()
            }
        }
        return lazyMap(self, lf: f)
    }
}
```

This however does not run in the playground, failing to compile with error below:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'LazyList<A>' to expected argument type 'LazyList<_>'
                return LazyList.Elem(x: lf(e), xs: {() -> LazyList<B> in return lazyMap(es(), lf: lf)})
```

How can I get it to compile? Is it because the compiler cannot infer the return type of `lazyMap`?

Comment: You didn't define the `<A>` parameter of LazyList for the extension - I would have expected `extension LazyList<A>`

Comment: According to [Apple docs on extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID185) it's not necessary to provide type parameters in definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply remove the "LazyList." from your switch cases :)

```
enum LazyList<A>{
    case Elem(x: A, xs: () -> LazyList<A>)
    case Nil()
}

extension LazyList {
    func map<B>(f: (A) -> B) -> LazyList<B> {
        func lazyMap(l: LazyList<A>, lf: (A) -> B) -> LazyList<B> {
            switch l {
            case let .Elem(e, es):
                return .Elem(x: lf(e), xs: {() -> LazyList<B> in return lazyMap(es(), lf: lf)})
            case .Nil:
                return .Nil()
            }
        }
        return lazyMap(self, lf: f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious though, what's the difference between elements returned by my original example and those without `LazyList` prefix?

Comment: removing the ```LazyList``` prefix simply allowed swift to infer the return type. Instead of dropping the prefix you could also replace ```LazyList.Elem``` with ```LazyList<B>.Elem```